# XPages - get all components by class possible?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

For my application I would like to validate if at least one of all xp:checkBox controls belonging to a certain category or class are checked.

Is there something similar to jquery class selector in XPages possible? e.g. get all controls with a certain style class and loop through them?

Comment: front or backend ?

Comment: I need it for my back-end validation. I am reading about facesContext.getViewRoot() and then getchildren(). then I have to iterate through all items nad compare them which UIComponent it is

Comment: I am also wondering if XspQuery can help me in some form ?

Answer (score 0):

### You could use the core control `Check Box Group`

*Take a look at the following example:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:messages id="errormessages"></xp:messages>

    <xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroupA">
        <xp:this.validators>
            <xp:validateRequired message="Please select one checkbox of this group!"></xp:validateRequired>
        </xp:this.validators>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="A-A"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="A-B"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="A-C"></xp:selectItem>
    </xp:checkBoxGroup>

    <xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroupB">
        <xp:this.validators>
            <xp:validateRequired message="Please select one checkbox of this group!"></xp:validateRequired>
        </xp:this.validators>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="B-A"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="B-B"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="B-C"></xp:selectItem>
    </xp:checkBoxGroup>

    <xp:button value="Submit" id="btnSubmit">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("submit to server");}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>


</xp:view>
```